# How to use ffmpeg.wasm in Firefox without getting the SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, webassembly, sharedarraybuffer

I'm trying to load ffmpeg.wasm in a react app to do a small video converter project. The code is working fine on chrome, but in firefox dev edition (83.0b) I catch the following error:

> ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined

Here's the part of the component where the error is catched (the variable ready is never becomes true):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from './App.module.css'
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg'
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true })

function App() {
  // load state
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)
  // files state
  const [video, setVideo] = useState('')
  const [gif, setGif]   = useState()
  // UI state
  const [dragOver, setDragOver ] = useState(false)
  const [nOfEnters, setNOfEnters] = useState(0)

  const load = async () => {
    try {
      await ffmpeg.load()
      setReady(true)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    load()
  }, [])
```

Thanks in advance, let me know if I should've provided any more detail.

Comment: How did you end up solving this issue? I am facing the same issue. How did you modify the headers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding these headers in the server response:

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

You can find some details here: https://web.dev/coop-coep/

Comment: Now it works on Firefox desktop but not on Firefox mobile. Getting the same error as above: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined. What do you suggest?

Comment: @kebsu I am facing the same issue as pedro. how can i add these headers in the code above?

Comment: @Juliette you need to have a control over the server code and add it there

Comment: checkout this link, https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer

Answer (score 1):

Adding the headers was only part of the solution for me.

First in Apache I needed to enable mod_header

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Then I could set the headers in `mysite.conf` file

```
Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

I was still getting the error after this though and needed to create an SSL certificate and setup Apache for HTTPS.

Generate SSL certificate

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 1095 -newkey rsa:2048 -out /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
```

Set up Apachce

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf
```

Then edit the `000-default-ssl.conf` file

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
```

https://hallard.me/enable-ssl-for-apache-server-in-5-minutes/