# FFmpeg.wasm stopped working after adding cross origin headers

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webassembly

I was having the [SharedArrayBuffer error as described in this other issue](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/issues/231) and to fix I added the cross origin isolation as suggested (also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65289040/2414842)) by adding the headers

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

After that, now when I try to run the code I just got **Uncaught ReferenceError: FFmpeg is not defined**. The error is happening on Firefox

My code is:

```
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.10.0/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    const { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } = FFmpeg; //error happens here
    const ffmpegInstance = createFFmpeg({
        corePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.10.0/dist/ffmpeg-core.js',
        log: true,
    });
 </script>
```

**Before that**, on Brave browser the process ran ok without having to add the Cross origin headers and also `FFmpeg` variable was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that for SharedArrayBuffer to work, the scripts using its functionality must opt-in via those headers as well.

Unfortunately, https://unpkg.com/ currently doesn't serve scripts with COOP/COEP headers.

To make your application work again, you'll have to either copy and self-host those sources from your own origin, or bundle them as part of your application.

Comment: That's strange because I still have status 200 after get request from unpkg...

Comment: If i load the .js scripts locally then it fails with 404 error `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.wasm` and `GEThttp://127.0.0.1:3000/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.worker.js`.. the scripts try to load the other resources locally...

Comment: Well it fails with 404 only because you don't have those resources. Either download all of them manually, or, the easiest, use npm: `npm install @ffmpeg/ffmpeg @ffmpeg/core` (from https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm README).

Then you'll have a copy with everything needed in `node_modules/@ffmpeg/...` which you can access from your script.

Comment: @RReverser Does that mean you can't use ffmpeg.wasm without node.js? I am hosting my static files (without a server) and it seems like there is no way out from the CORS error.

Comment: Not necessarily Node.js, no. Any server that allows you to configure headers should work.